# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-\omega(\frac{1}{n}))^n=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-o(\frac{1}{n}))^n=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Could you help me to show that

(1) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-\omega(\frac{1}{n}))^n=0$

(2) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-o(\frac{1}{n}))^n=1$

where $o(\cdot)$ is little $o$ notation described [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/Asymptotic_notations#Little_o_notation) and $\omega(\cdot)$ is little $\omega$ notation described [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/Asymptotic_notations#Little_omega_notation)

Comment: I think you need to be careful: your $\omega(1/n)$ should also be bounded above in magnitude by $1$. For instance just the sequence $-2$ is $\omega(1/n)$ but that certainly violates your first equality.

Comment: Little-$o$ is handled in this answer from me: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933

Comment: Actually, I made a minor error: your $\omega(1/n)$ needs to be between $0$ and $2$, and it can't have $2$ as a limit point. Otherwise everything's OK.