# Limit of Function of Convergent Sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $a_n$ be a real valued sequence.  Assume that 
$a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.  Use this to prove that $(1+a_n/n)^n\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

This proof would be simple if it wasn't for that pesky exponent.  I suspect that I"m supposed to use the Bernoulli inequality to solve this somehow, along with monotone convergence theorem.  But I'm just really struggling to make any progress with this.  Any advice?

Comment: The limit should be $1$, not $0$. It's tending towards $e^0 = 1$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I fixed the typo.

Comment: This is a marvelous lemma I learnt on this website courtesy Thomas Andrews : see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/72031 This is especially useful in the development of the theory of exponential functions based on definition $$\exp(z) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\dfrac{z}{n}\right)^{n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let observe that the limit trivially holds for $a_n=0$, thus without loss of generality assume $a_n\neq 0$.

**1. Proof by log**

Note that

$$(1+a_n/n)^n=e^{n\log(1+a_n/n)}\sim e^{a_n}\to 1$$

indeed

$$\log(1+a_n/n)=\frac{a_n}{n}\frac{\log(1+a_n/n)}{a_n/n}\sim \frac{a_n}{n}$$

**2. Proof by squeeze theorem**

As an alternative note that by Bernoulli and by $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\le e$ we have that

$$1+a_n=1+n\frac{a_n}{n}\le \left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n\le \left(1+\frac{|a_n|}{n}\right)^n=\left[\left(1+\frac{|a_n|}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{|a_n|}}\right]^{|a_n|}\le e^{|a_n|}$$

thus by squeeze theorem

$$\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n\to 1$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use logarithms in this proof.  That's why I suspected that I needed to use the Bernoulli inequality and monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: sorry I didn’t get this request by the OP

Comment: I don’t think that monoticity can help since $a_n$ has not continditions on that, maybe squeeze theorem

Comment: You may have a look at the proof given in linked answer (see comments to question) which uses inequalities and does not need any stuff like $\log$ or $e$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh what about the second proof given here by Bernoulli and $(1+1/n)^n<e$ via squeeze theorem? Thanks for the link

Comment: That's also fine. I had forgot a +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh your check is one of the best I could have, Thanks

Comment: Just add that the Inequality trivially holds even when $a_n=0$ for some $n$. You are using $n/a_n$ so you implicitly assume $a_n\neq 0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes that’s right, I’ll fix that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(i). For $x\geq 0$ we have $$0\leq \ln (1+x)=\int_1^{1+x}\frac {1}{y}dy\leq \int_1^{1+x} 1dy=x.$$ (ii).  For $z\in (-1,0)$ we have $$0> \ln (1-z)=\int_1^{1-z}\frac {1}{y}dy>\int_1^{1-z}\frac {1}{1-z}dz= \frac {-z}{1-z}.$$

(iii). Since $a_n\to 0$ we have  $|a_n/n|<1$ for all but finitely many $n.$

(iv). If $a_n\geq 0$ then by (i) we have $$0\leq \ln ((1+a_n/n)^n)=n\ln (1+a_n/n)\leq  n(a_n/n)=a_n=|a_n|.$$ (v).  If $-1<a_n/n$ then  by (ii) we have $$0>\ln ((1+a_n/n)^n)=n\ln (1+a_n/n)=n\ln (1-|a_n/n|)>n\frac {-|a_n/n|}{1-|a_n/n|}=$$ $$=-\frac {|a_n|}{1-|a_n|/n}.$$ (vi). By (iv) and (v), when  $|a_n/n|<1$ we  have $$|\ln ((1+a_n/n)^n)|\leq \max\left(|a_n|, \frac  {|a_n|}{1-|a_n|/n}\right)=\frac {|a_n|}{1-|a_n|/n}.$$  Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln ((1+a_n/n)^n)=0.$