# Prove the limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Assume that $x_n$ is a sequence such that $x_n$ converge to a constant $x$.
I would like to prove that

$\left( 1+ x_n/n \right)^n \rightarrow e^x$

Obvious if $x_n = x$ the result would be given. The extra sequence complicates things and I would like a hint or solution on how to proof this.

Answer (score 2):

If you know/accept that the result holds for $x_n=x$ then the proof is easily completed by the following [lemma of Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/72031) :

> **Lemma**: If $n(a_n-1)\to 0$ then $a_n^n\to 1$.

Now let $$a_n=\dfrac{1+\dfrac{x_n}{n}}{1+\dfrac{x}{n}}$$ and check that $n(a_n-1)\to 0$.