# Intuition for Euler's formula by using the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

My goal is to give good intuition as to why the formula
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$

Is correct. I don't need to be formal or rigorous.

One good way of doing this is by looking at the taylor expansion of $e^x$ for real values of $x$, substituting $x=i\theta$ and getting the taylor expansions for $\cos$ and $\sin$.

**What I want**: To give a similar intuitive explanation **without** using taylor expansions.

What I do have: The equality

$$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

So, I can ask myself what happens with this formula when I substitute $x=i\theta$. But I'm not sure what happens now - can we really proceed from this starting point to get an intuition for Euler's formula?

Comment: Yes, @robjohn posted a detailed answer related to this somewhere. I can’t quite find the post right now though

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291754/815585) answer your question?

Comment: For an intuitive understanding, try looking at $e^{i\theta}e^{i\phi} =e^{i(\theta+\phi)}$ and $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)$  compared to  $\cos(\theta+\phi)+i\sin(\theta+\phi)$ to see that they behave as you might expect.

Comment: $f(\theta)=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ has the properties $f(0) = 1$ , $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$  and $f'(x) = i f(x)$ .  The only solution is $f(x) = e^{ix}$

Comment: A simple proof of the limit in question for all complex values of $x$ is given in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3000717/72031).

Answer (score 1):

You could denote $\mathrm{cis}\theta=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$, and show (with induction and trigonometric angle addition formulas) that $\mathrm{cis}(n\theta) = (\mathrm{cis}\theta)^n$. (Showing first that $\mathrm{cis}(\theta+\phi)$ = $\mathrm{cis}\theta\cdot\mathrm{cis}\phi$ may or may not be easier.)

Then use the fact that for small $\theta$, $\sin\theta\approx\theta$ and $\cos\theta\approx 1$ to find
$e^{i\theta}\approx\left(1+\frac{i\theta}{n}\right)^n\approx\left(\mathrm{cis}\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)\right)^n=\mathrm{cis}\theta=\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, where the approximation becomes exact as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

In order to have a better understanding of Euler’s formula, you should picture yourself the two-dimensional complex plane. In fact, the right side of the equation describes the circular motion along the outside of the unit unit circle using sine and cosine. That is, if we set $\theta = \pi$, then that means that we travel $\pi$-units along the unit circle. We are then half way around the circle, i.e. we’re at $-1 = e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)$.

Comment: It is a good intuition and I like to use it, but I need to relate it to one of the standard definitions of $e^x$; in this case, the limit-based one. That's the content of my question.

Comment: When taking into account the given definition of exp(x), it can be shown that exp($i\theta$) will have magnitude 1 and angle x for $\lim_{n \to \infty}$, which is the same as the expression on the right side of the equation.