# limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)^n$

Tags: limits, factorial

I'm having trouble resolving the following limit:  $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)^n $$ Intuituvely the limit is equal to 1, but the exercises requires me to resolve via calculation and I have no idea how I can accomplish this. 
Can someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)^{n!}\right]^{\frac1{(n-1)!}}$$

then refer to standard limit for $e$. How can we conclude form here?

Answer (score 9):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a solution that relies on elementary inequalities and the squeeze theorem only.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

Using the inequality $1+x\le \frac1{1-x}$, for $x<1$, along with Bernoulli's Inequality, we have for $n\ge 2$

$$1\le \left(1+\frac1{n!}\right)^n\le \frac1{\left(1-\frac1{n!}\right)^n}\le \frac1{1-\frac1{(n-1)!}}$$

whereby application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit.

Comment: It is a very elegant way which only make use of simple results, the only issue is to have great the idea to start with the inequality $1+x\le \frac1{1-x}$ as $(x<1)$ and take is as a given.

Comment: Well, for all $x$, $x^2\ge 0$.  Hence, $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2\le 1$.  For $x<1$, $1+x\le \frac1{1-x}$.   So, that is a fairly standard "trick."

Comment: Yes indeed the proof is simple maybe it is less obviuos have the idea to strat with it. Of course it is a good trick to keep in mind :)

Comment: Yes, this "trick" can be used, for example, to show that $\exp(x)\exp(y)=\exp(x+y)$ where we use the limit characterization $\exp(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ of the exponential function.

Answer (score 5):

It suffices to compute the limit of the logarithm and show that it equals zero. Namely note that
$$
n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)=n\times \frac{1}{n!}\times \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)}{1/n!}
$$
Now let $n\to \infty$. Using the fact that
$$
\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\log(1+u)-\log1}{u-0}=1
$$
by definition of the derivative we get that
$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\times \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)}{1/n!}\to0\times 1=0
$$
as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{n!}<\frac{1}{n(n-1)}<\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}
$$
Now prove that
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t}=0
$$
and observe that
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\right)^n&=
\left(1+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\right)^{n-1}
\\[6px]
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}\right)\exp\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\right)
\end{align}
Finally note that
$$
1\le\left(1+\frac{1}{n!}\right)^n
$$

Answer (score 3):

Since Mark Viola has already used the elementary approach of Bernoulli inequality here is one more approach via binomial theorem.

We use the following [lemma of Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/72031) (proved using binomial theorem):

> **Lemma**: If $\{a_n\} $ is a sequence of real or complex terms such that $n(a_n-1)\to 0$ then $a_n^n\to 1$.

Now use $a_n=1+(1/n!)$ and check that $n(a_n-1)=1/(n-1)!\to 0$. The desired limit is $1$ by the above lemma.

Comment: (+1)  Nice use of that "lemma."