# Proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}=1$ without L'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}=1$$
using L'Hospital's rule. But is there a way to prove it without L'Hospital's rule? I tried splitting it as
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-n}(n^2+x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}},$$
but that didn't work because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2+x^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:  Direct Application of Bernoulli's Inequality**

Note that for $n>|x|$

$$1\le \left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}\le \frac1{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}}\le \frac1{1-\frac{x^2}{2n}}$$

where we used Bernoulli's inequality to arrive at the last inequality.

Now apply the squeeze theorem to find

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}=1$$

---

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$:  Using Estimates of the Logarithm Function**

Note that we may write

$$\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}=e^{(n/2)\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)}\tag 1$$

In [This Answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I used elementary, pre-calculus tools to obtain the inequalities

$$\frac{x}{1+x}\le \log(1+x)\le x \tag2$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$e^{nx^2/(2n^2+2x^2)}\le e^{(n/2)\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)}\le e^{x^2/2n}$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted result

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2}=1$$

as expected!

Comment: @MrPink Is your user name an homage to Steve Buscemi's character in Reservoir Dogs?  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  ;-)

Comment: The proof with logarithm helped me, thanks for your answer. When I was creating my account, it automatically generated a pink profile picture, so I renamed myself to Mr Pink.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

This has the form $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^{n}=e$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}{\color{red} {\frac{n}{x^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{n}} }}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{x^2}}\right)^{{\color{red} {\frac{x^2}{2n}} }}=e^{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2n}} = e^0 = 1$$

**Note** Since $n\to\infty$ then $1/n^2$ has the same behaivor that $1/(n^2/x^2) = x^2/n^2$.

Comment: I like this. It solves the problem very quickly.

Comment: I wonder for that phantom, that gives downvote but doesn't say why.

Comment: +1 I was playing with this idea when I found your answer. Nice job !!!.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following for large n and finite x:
$$e^{\frac{x^2}{n^2}} \approx 1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}$$ 
Therefore, rewrite the limit as:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\left(e^{\frac{x^2}{n^2}}\right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{x^2}{2n}}$$
$$=1$$

Comment: This is not a proof. You have to be more explicit about controlling the error.

Comment: Hi Ty.  This lacks rigor.  Better to use inequalities or asymptotic expansions here.

Comment: Ty. If you want to use any parts of my answer to complete yours, welcome. I can delete mine.

Comment: @PeterSzilas It's fine, I don't care.  There is already other answers on this post.

Comment: Never mind the other answers. Your idea is good, just add  one or two steps.

Answer (score 1):

I have an algebraic solution. Let's our limit be $L$:
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n}{2}$$
Now, we make two changes of variables: $$t = \frac{n}{2} $$ and
$$y=\frac{x^2}{4}$$
Then we have:
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n}{2}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2t^2}\right)^t=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{y}{t^2}\right)^t$$
Then, rewrite our limit as:
$$L=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{y}{t^2}\right)^t=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{t \ln{\left(1+\frac{y}{t^2}\right)}}=e^{\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} t \ln{\left(1+\frac{y}{t^2}\right)}}=e^{L_1}$$
Where $L_1=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} t \ln{\left(1+\frac{y}{t^2}\right)}$

Now, we make another change of variables:
$$r=1/t^2$$
$$L_1=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} t \ln{\left(1+\frac{y}{t^2}\right)}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln{\left(1+ry\right)}}{\sqrt{r}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln{\left(1+ry\right)}}{yr} \frac{yr}{\sqrt{r}}=\lim_{r\rightarrow0} y\sqrt{r}=0$$
Finally:
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)^\frac{n}{2}=e^{L_1}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Just one comment: Everytime you do $L = \lim ()$ you are saying that in fact, this limit exists. Before that line, you have to justify that the limit exists, and after then you can write  $L = \lim ()$ without any problem :D

Comment: Oh, you are right

Answer (score 0):

For the upper bound using Bernoulli inequality note that it applies for exponents $t: t \leq 0 \cup t \geq 1$, so for $\frac{n}{2} < 0$:
$$
\bigg(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2} \bigg)^\frac{n}{2}= \frac{1}{\bigg(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2} \bigg)^{-\frac{n}{2}}} \leq \frac{1}{1- \frac{x^2}{2n}} \to 1
$$
And the limit follows to squeeze lemma

Answer (score 0):

The [lemma of Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/72031) can be used here:

> **Lemma**: If $n(a_n-1)\to 0$ then $a_n^n\to 1$.

Now use this with $$a_n=\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}}$$

---

Perhaps you are trying to deal with the limit of $(1+ix/n)^n$ and show that it equals $\cos x+i\sin x$. That can also be easily handled by the lemma in question without first dealing with $|(1+ix/n)^n|$. Just apply the lemma to $$a_n=\dfrac{1 +\dfrac{ix} {n}} {\cos\dfrac{x} {n} +i\sin\dfrac{x} {n}} $$

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128931/121671) that for any sequence (real or complex) $z_n\rightarrow z$,

$$
\Big(1+\frac{z_n}{n}\Big)^n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^z
$$