# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \alpha$ imply $\lim \left(1+ \frac {a_n}{n} \right) =e^\alpha$ for real value

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Does $\lim_{n \to \infty}  a_n = \alpha$   imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \frac {a_n}{n} \right)^n =e^\alpha$?

I'm only considering real value
and also, does the value of $\alpha$ makes a difference?\

I tried considering $$\left|\left(1+ \frac {a_n}{n} \right)^n-e^\alpha\right|\leq\left|\left(1+ \frac {a_n}{n} \right)^n-\left(1+ \frac {\alpha}{n} \right)^n\right|+\left|\left(1+ \frac {\alpha}{n} \right)^n-e^\alpha\right|$$
I know that for any fixed $\alpha$, $\left|\left(1+ \frac {\alpha}{n} \right)^n-e^\alpha\right|$ tends to zero.

But I don't know how to deal with $$\left|\left(1+ \frac {a_n}{n} \right)^n-\left(1+ \frac {\alpha}{n} \right)^n\right|$$, I tried binomial expansion but didn't get anywhere. Is this where the value of $\alpha$ come to matter？
Thanks

Comment: Look at the lemma  at the top of this answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933

Comment: In particular, it is easier to show $$\left(\frac{1+\frac{a_n}{n}}{1+\frac{\alpha}n}\right)^n\to 1$$ than it is to prove the difference goes to zero.

Comment: Here is another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128931/121671) in the case $a_n$ is a complex convergence sequence.

Comment: Thank you! That lemma is a really cool approach to me, I wonder where I can learn more about this? I could understand the lemma, but I don’t feel like I’ve grasped its full meaning, and the minus 1 in  n*g(n)-1  seem somewhat not so straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** If $a_n\to \alpha > 0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $b_n := na_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Therefore, make the substitution $n \mapsto na_n$ in the limit, which yields the following equality:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\bigg)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1+\frac{a_n}{na_n}\bigg)^{na_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{na_n}$$

Does this help?

Comment: That plays fast and loose with the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ notation. which usually implies that $n$ is an integer limit. But if we know that the real limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{x}\right)^{x}\to e^{\alpha},$$ this argument works.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer: look for [duplicates](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba_n%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%5En%24&p=1)

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you! 
Just to check, I can make this substitution because both n and bn go to infinity while an is finite right?

Answer (score 1):

It requires breaking up the expansion of $e^a$ into two parts depending on $\epsilon$.  Let $N_1$ be defined by $\sum\limits_{k=N_1+1}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}\lt \epsilon$.  Then the binomial expansion can be used on the sum to $N_1$.  Let $N_2$ be defined by $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N_1} \binom{n}{k}|a_n^k-a^k|\lt \epsilon$ for $n\gt N_2$.  Let $N=max(N_1,N_2)$  Expansion differences should be $\lt 2\epsilon$ for $n\gt N$.

To handle the tails for $a_n$ would require a little work showing $|\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^n\binom{n}{k}a_n^k-\sum\limits_{k=N_1+1}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}|\lt \sum\limits_{k=N_1+1}^\infty \frac{a^k}{k!}$ for $n\gt N$.