# Why does $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{2^n} $ not equal $\sqrt{e}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{2^n}$ with

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{2^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{(4^\frac{1}{2})^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{4^\frac{n}{2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}((1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{4^n})^\frac{1}{2} = ({e})^\frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{e}.$$

However, I know that the correct answer is $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{4^n})^{2^n} = 1$. So at what point did I make a mistake? Which move was not allowed?

Comment: Your third equal sign is wrong.

Comment: I second @JetfiRex. Consider 2^3^2. (2^3)^2 = 64, but 2^(3^2) = 512.

Comment: Umm.  $ 0 \leq \log(1 + x) \leq x$   for $ x \geq 0.$  Take log of your expression, $$2^n \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{4^n} \right) \leq 2^n \cdot \frac{1}{4^n}   = \frac{2^n}{4^n}   =  \frac{1}{2^n}  $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in general $\sqrt{A^x} = A^{\frac{x}{2}} \not = A^{\sqrt{x}}$ [as in general $\frac{x}{2} \not = \sqrt{x}$]. Try $A=2$ and $x=9$ to see for yourself.

In particular here: $$\left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{2^n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{\sqrt{4^n}} \not = \sqrt{\left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{4^n}}.$$

Instead:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{2^n} = \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{4^n}\right)^{2^{-n}},$$ and as the inequality $4 \ge \left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{4^n} \ge 1$ holds for each $n$, it follows that, on the one hand:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{2^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{4^n}\right)^{2^{-n}}$$
$$\le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 4^{2^{-n}} = 1.$$

And on the other hand:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{2^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{4^n}\right)^{2^{-n}}$$
$$\ge \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1^{2^{-n}} = 1.$$

Thus indeed,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)^{2^n}  = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is slightly different argument.

A well known result in Calculus states that

> If $a_n$ is a numeric sequence (real or complex) and that $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$, then
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\Big)^n=e^{a}$$

This result has been discussed before in MSE in other contexts, see for for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128931/121671).

Now,
$$A_n:=\Big(1+\frac{1}{4^n}\Big)^{2^n}=\Big(1+\frac{2^{-n}}{2^n}\Big)^{2^n}$$
Then, as from the result mentioned above, the sequence $A_n$ converges to $e^{\lim_n 2^{-n}}=e^0=1$.

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback from whoever downvoted my posting.