# How to rigorously prove this limit? $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^n$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I would like to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^n$. $0< \alpha<1$.

I asked my friend and he telled me that $$(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^n=[(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^{n^{\alpha+o(1)}})]^{n^{1-\alpha-o(1)}}$$.

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^{n^{\alpha+o(1)}}=e^{-1}$, we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^n=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-n^{1-\alpha-o(1)}}=0$$
I don't think it is rigorous. I have the following two main questions.

(1) How to show  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^{n^{\alpha+o(1)}}=e^{-1}$? I know  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha})^{n^{\alpha}}=e^{-1}$ but I don't know how to deal with extra o(1).

(2) How can we somehow first evaluate the limit inside the exponential? By the same reasoning, I think we can have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)})^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-n^{-\alpha+o(1)}))^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1^n=1$, which results in a totally different answer.

Comment: Here is one [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128931/121671)

Comment: If we want to use that approach, we have to set $c_n=-n^{1-\alpha+o(1)}$, which does not converge. How could we use that approach?

Comment: It diverges to $-\infty$, provided $o(1)$ is real, which still works. In any case, for a real sequence $a_n\rightarrow 0$,
$$E_n:=\big(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+a_n}}\Big)^{n^{\alpha+a_n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-1}$$
since $0<e^{-1}<1$, for all $n$ large enough, say all $n\geq N$ for some $N$, $E:=\sup_{n\geq N}E_n<1$. $E^{n^{1-\alpha-a_n}}\rightarrow0$

Comment: I see how the first approach works. However, I can't understand why in the proof we have $$max_{1\leq j \leq n}\{|z_j|,|w_j|\}\leq e ^{\frac{\gamma}{n}}$$ We have no control for $n< n_0$. Sorry to comment here, I don't have enough reputaion to comment there.