# Evaluating $\left( \int_0^a e^{x^2/n} dx\right)^n$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

> Given a real number $a > 0$, I need to find
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \int_0^a e^{x^2/n} dx\right)^n
> $$

I really have no idea where to start, should I write down the function below the integral and somehow use the dominant convergence theorem?

Comment: Just like the feedback you received on your last problem, please explain the background behind this problem or any other details that would improve the quality of this question. Remember question quality is about making this problem as interesting to would be solvers as it is providing better context for where such techniques or ideas belong.

Comment: Play around with this in Wolfram Alpha and see if you notice any patterns.

Comment: Letting $x=u\sqrt n$ the integral is $$\sqrt{n}\int_0^{a/\sqrt n} e^{u^2}du$$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: No idea where to start? How about $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{x^2}{n}}$

Comment: You are going to need $a<1,$ because $e^{x^2/n}\geq 1$ so the value is at least $a^n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews over here ruining my kind of crappy hint 

Comment: For $f(n)^n$ to converge, with $f$ differentiable, you either need it to converge to zero, or you need $$f(n)=1+\frac bn+o\left(\frac 1n\right)$$

Comment: How can you multiply $n^n$ to the value and not affect the limit? @OliverDiaz

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: the only difficulty is when $a=1$. The cases $0<a<1$ and $a>1$ are simple.

Comment: @popmaria Do you know Taylor's formula? Writing $\mathrm{e}^{\frac{x^2}{n}}=1+\frac{x^2}{n}+\mathcal{O}_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ then integrating, you will eventually compute $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\exp\left[n\left(\ln(a)+\ln\left(1+\frac{a^2}{3n}+\mathcal{O}_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\right)\right]$ whose value depends on $a$.

Comment: You may rewrite your expression as $$\Big(\int^a_0 e^{x^2/n}\,dx \Big)^n=\left(a\tfrac{\sqrt{n}}{a}\int^{\tfrac{a}{\sqrt{n}}}_0 e^{u^2}\,du\right)^n$$ Notice that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{h}\int^h_0 e^{u^2}\,du=1$.
When $a=1$ one has
$$\Big( \sqrt{n}\int^{1/\sqrt{n}}_0e^{u^2}-1+1\,du\Big)^n=\left(\frac{ n^{3/2}\int^{n^{-1/2}}_0(e^{u^2}-1)\,du}{n} +1\right)^n=$$
Notice that
$$\frac{1}{h^3}\int^h_0(e^{u^2}-1)\,du\sim\frac{e^{h^2}-1}{3h^2}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}\frac13$$
Other cases $0<a<1$ and $a>1$ are trivial.

Comment: @OliverDiaz directing that to me is pointless. That is the site policy now apparently. I'm only doing my best to try to make sure everyone goes with what the majority wants.

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n=\int_{0}^a e^{x^2/n}dx =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)n^k k!}$$

This converges to $a$ as $n\to\infty.$ In particular, if $0<a<1$ $I_n^n\to 0,$ and if $a>1,$ then $I_n^n\to\infty.$

So the only interesting case is $a=1.$

Then $n(I_n-1)\to \frac{1}{3}.$

So, by the [Lemma here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933), $I^n_n\to e^{1/3}.$

Comment: Really nice answer.

Comment: @K.defaoite: ... to a very nice problem.

Answer (score 2):

If $a<1,$ then

$$\left (\int_0^a e^{x^2/n}\, dx \right)^n < (a\cdot e^{1/n})^n = a^n\cdot e \to 0.$$

If $a>1,$ then as Thomas Andrews pointed out, we have

$$\left(\int_0^a e^{x^2/n}\,dx\right)^n > \left(\int_0^a 1\,dx\right)^n = a^n \to \infty.$$

For $a=1,$ let's use $e^u= 1 +u + o(u),$ which follows from the definition of the derivative of $e^u$ at $0.$ We then get

$$\int_0^1 e^{x^2/n}\, dx = \int_0^1 (1+x^2/n + o(1/n))\,dx$$ $$ = 1+1/(3n)+ o(1/n).$$

Raising to the $n$th power, we get $(1+1/(3n)+ o(1/n))^n \to e^{1/3}.$

Comment: The $a>1$ case is much easier: $e^{x^2/n}\geq 1$ so the integral is $\geq a.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Oops, palm hits forehead. You're right, thanks.