# Given $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\epsilon_n) = 0$, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \epsilon_n \frac {x}{n})^n= 1$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

My solution to this problem is as follows:

> Let $\epsilon_n$ be a sequence of numbers that converge to $0$. Let $c = \epsilon_n x$, where $x \in \Re$. Then, using the limit definition of $e^x$ we can write:$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + \frac {c}{n})^n = e^c$$
> As $n \to \infty$, $c \to 0$ and $e^c \to 1$. $$\therefore \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + \epsilon_n\frac {x}{n})^n = 1$$

Is this solution valid? I'm not sure if my use of the limit definition of $e^x$ is correct here.

Comment: The formula for $e^c$ in principle is for fixed $c$. Your $c$ depends on $n$.

Comment: Why not writng $\left(1+\epsilon_n\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left[n\ln\left(1+\epsilon_n\frac{x}{n}\right)\right]$ then using Taylor's formula at $1$ for the $\ln$?

Comment: I don’t think that answer is valid. You are taking $c\epsilon_n$ as a constant, and letting it approach zero after letting $n\to\infty.$ But see the Lemma in this answer, particularly the firs case of $0$:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are a lot of ways to solve it. But your solution seems lack of some rigour, I try to improve it a little bit in the following

---

For example, because the sequence $\epsilon_n$ converges to $0$, for all $c>0$ we can always find an $N$ such that $|\epsilon_n x|<c $ for all $n>N$. And that implies that:
$$\limsup_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon}{n})^n \le \limsup_n (1+\frac{c}{n})^n =e^c $$
for all $c>0$, hence
$$\limsup_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon_n}{n})^n \le 1$$.
Similarly, you can also show that:
$$\liminf_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon}{n})^n \ge \liminf_n (1-\frac{c}{n})^n =e^{-c} $$
for all $c>0$,
Hence $$\liminf_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon_n}{n})^n \ge 1$$
So, from two observations above, we can conclude that:
$$\lim_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon_n}{n})^n =1$$

Comment: If you use `\left(` and `\right)` you get better parentheses:$$\left(1+\frac cn\right)^n$$

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. The $\le 0$ is just a typo.

Comment: For $n$ big enough, you see that $ x\epsilon_n<C$

Comment: in the liminf, it was a typo, the inequality should be the other way. I corrected it.

Comment: Sorry, I want to clarify my question. My question is why do you need to use the concept of limit superior and limit inferior in the first place. Since, for all $c>0$, we can always find an N such that $|\epsilon_n x| < c$ for all $n>N$, we can write: $$(1 - \frac {c}{n})^n < (1 + \frac {\epsilon_n x}{n})^n < (1 + \frac {c}{n})^n$$ If we take limit of this inequality as n approaches $\infty$, we get $$e^{-c} < \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\epsilon_n \frac{x}{n}\right)^n < e^c$$

Comment: Okay. Because, you don't know if $\lim (1+ \frac{\epsilon_nx}{n})^n$ exists, you can't use that expression into your calculations. However, this is not the case with limsup and liminf because they always exist.

Comment: One more question, in the following inequalities: $$\limsup_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon_n}{n})^n \le \limsup_n (1+\frac{c}{n})^n =e^c, \\ \liminf_n (1+\frac{x\epsilon_n}{n})^n \geq \liminf_n (1-\frac{c}{n})^n =e^{-c}$$ can't we make the inequalities stricter so that its just less than or greater than? As from the inequality $|\epsilon_n x| < c$ we can get the inequality $$(1 + \frac {\epsilon_n x}{n})^n < (1 + \frac {c}{n})^n$$ so can't we apply the limit superior to this inequality? (Similar case for limit inferior)

Comment: From the inequality $a_n < b_n$, the best you can have is $\limsup a_n \le  \limsup b_n$ ( not the strict inequality), so I guess what you want does not matter in the end.

Comment: By all means,  to conclude, you don't care  if it is the strict inequality or not, so why should we be concerned by that?

Comment: I just wanted to ask to deepen my understanding, as I thought we could have a stricter inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss take $x \ge 0$. Break $\epsilon_n$ to a positive and/or a negative subsequence.

Considering the subsequence $\epsilon_{n_k} \ge 0$, using $e^y \ge 1+y$ when $y \ge 0$:

\begin{equation}
1 \le (1+\epsilon_{n_k} x/n_k)^{n_k} \le e^{\epsilon_{n_k} x}
\end{equation}

Then take the limit $\epsilon_{n_k} \rightarrow 0$.
For the $\epsilon_{n_k} \le 0$ subsequence, since $f(y) = (1+y)^n, |y| < 1$ is convex:

\begin{equation}
1 \ge (1 + \epsilon_{n_k} x/n_k)^{n_k} \ge 2 - (1 - \epsilon_{n_k}x/n_k)^{n_k}, n_k \text{ large enough}
\end{equation}

where we used using $(1/2)f(y) + (1/2)f(-y) \ge f(0)$. We get the same limit, therefore the whole sequence converges to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is correct.

**Alternate Method -**

Let $y=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\epsilon_n \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$. This means,
$$\ln(y)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\ln(1+\epsilon_n \frac{x}{n})\cdot\frac{1}{n^{-1}}\right)\approx\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\left(\epsilon_n \frac{x}{n}+O\left((e_n\frac{x}{n})^2\right)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{n^{-1}}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x\epsilon_n+nO\left((e_n\frac{x}{n})^2\right))=0$$
Hence, $y=1$.

Comment: No, the OPs solution is not correct. And this is essentially correct, but you need to be more precise about what $\approx$ means.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\varepsilon_n \frac xn\right)^n=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n/\varepsilon_n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{n/\varepsilon_n}\right)^{n/\varepsilon_n}\right]^{\varepsilon_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e^x)^{\varepsilon_n}=1.
$$

**Note:** This strategy works if $\varepsilon_n$ does not change sign, for $n > n_0$.

Comment: To claim $\lim_{n \to +\infty} (1 + \frac {x}{n/ \epsilon_n})^{n/ \epsilon_n}$ is equal to $e^x$ don't you first need to show $n/ \epsilon_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @DavidChoi Yes, you are correct... This approach works only if $\varepsilon_n >0$ (for $n>n_0$) because we need to be sure that $n/\varepsilon_n \to +\infty$.