# Does $(1 + f(x))^x \to e^k$ if $xf(x) \to k$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

It's well known that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{k}{x}\right)^x = e^k}$.

> Suppose $xf(x) \to k$ as $x \to \infty$. Do we necessarily have $(1 + f(x))^x \to e^k$?

If $f$ happens to be differentiable, and if we also have $\displaystyle{\frac{f'(x)}{-x^{-2}} \to k}$, then the answer to the above question is yes, as can be seen by an application of L'Hopital's rule. But without assuming this second limit exists, I don't think L'Hopital's rule is relevant.

If it's any easier, I'd also be interested in the answer for the special case when $k = 1$.

---

This is a problem I thought of as I was solving problem 3.2.1(b) (page 72) from "Problems in Mathematical Analysis I" by Kaczor and Nowak.

Comment: Closely related to, if not a duplicate of, [1 to the power of infinity formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987215/1-to-the-power-of-infinity-formula).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176253/given-lim-n-to-infty-epsilon-n-0-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-1 but with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon_n = c \ne 0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=k$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{k+o(1)}{x}$.

---

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

We assume in the following that $k>0$ although analogous analysis applies for $k< 0$. Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+f(x)\right)^x&=\left(1+\frac kx +o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^x\\\\
&=\left(1+\frac kx \right)^x\left(1+\frac {o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac kx}\right)^x\tag1
\end{align}$$

Now, applying Bernoulli's Inequality reveals (for $x$ sufficiently large)

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac {o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac kx}\right)^x\ge 1+\frac{o\left(1\right)}{1+\frac kx}\tag2
\end{align}$$

In addition, we have from Bernoulli's Inequality (for $x$ sufficiently large)

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac {o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac kx}\right)^x\le \frac1{\left(1-\frac {o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac kx}\right)^x}\le \frac1{1-\frac{o\left(1\right)}{1+\frac kx}}\tag3
\end{align}$$

Putting together $(2)$ and $(3)$ and applying the squeeze theorem we find that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac {o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+\frac kx}\right)^x=1\tag4$$

Finally, using $(4)$ in $(1)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+f(x)\right)^x=e^k$$

---

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

We begin by writing

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+f(x)\right)^x&=e^{x\log(1+f(x))}\\\\
&=e^{x\left(f(x)+O\left(f(x)^2\right)\right)}\tag5
\end{align}$$

Letting $x\to \infty$ in $(5)$, we find that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+f(x)\right)^x=e^k$$

as was to be shown!

---

Alternatively, since we can write

$$\frac{f(x)}{1+f(x)}\le \log(1+f(x))\le f(x)$$

Then we have the inequalities

$$e^{xf(x)/(1+f(x))}\le \left(1+f(x)\right)^x\le e^{xf(x)}$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem yields

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+f(x)\right)^x=e^k$$

Comment: I had the second method in mind as well. Great answer as always!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Hi Cameron!  Thank you!  And how are you?  It's been a while.

Comment: I've been well. How about you?

Comment: Method 2 makes sense (including the "alternatively" part). I also see how to change Method 1 to get another proof, but as stated, I believe (2) incorrectly applies Bernoulli's inequality. Namely, replacing $o(1/x)$ by $-1/x^2$ (and letting $k = 1$) gives a counterexample  to inequality (2), as [checked by wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x*ln%281+-+1%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+x%29%29+-+ln%281+-+1%2F%28x%5E2%28x%2B1%29%29%29+%3C+0).

Comment: @AndrewKelley Bernoulli's inequality states that $(1+t)^s\ge 1+st$ for every $s\ge 0$ and every $t>-1$.  Here $x\ge0$ and certainly for $k>0$ and $x$ sufficiently large, $$o(1/x)/(1+k/x) >-1$.  So, everything works.

Comment: @Mark, yes, I understand the statement of Bernoulli's inequality, but I think you made an algebra mistake. In particular, when applied to $(1 + o(1/x)/(1+k/x))^x$, Bernoulli's inequality gives a lower bound of $1 + x * o(1/x)/(1 + k/x) = 1 + x^2 * o(1/x)/(x+k)$

Comment: I had a typo in my comment from 2 minutes ago (forgetting the divide by symbol in the last expression)

Comment: The problem is that if $o(1/x)$ is negative, then $1 + x^2 * o(1/x)/(x+k)$ is not larger than $1 + o(1/x)/(x+k)$. The issue is not whether or not Bernoulli's inequality applies. It does. The issue is your lower bound does not match what Bernoulli's inequality gives.

Comment: @AndrewKelley Ah.  The typographical errata have been edited.  Thank you for the catch!

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your thorough answer. I appreciated that you gave multiple approaches. (It did take me some effort to fill in the details though.)

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.