# Evaluate : $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-2n}\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

My attempt:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-2n}\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}\\ =\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-2n}. \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-2n}.e^{2n}=1$$ Where did I go wrong? Please do help me to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the $e^{2n}$ comes from ? Also one of the factor goes to unfinity and the other one goes to 0 so you have undeterminate form.

Comment: Usual condition on applying $\lim fg = \lim f \cdot \lim g$ is that the right-hand side must be well-defined. It's not well-defined here (since $0 \cdot \infty$ is undefined).

Comment: You actually have an indeterminate form $1^\infty$

Comment: If you're also interested in what would be a correct treatment, here's a hint: using the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ or otherwise, evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}[n^2\ln(1+2/n)-2n]$.

Comment: You went wrong in substituting $(1+2/n)^{n^2}$ with $e^{2n}.$ While it is true that $(1+2/n)^n$ converges to $e^2,$ it is not true that you can replace this term with $e^{2n},$ since that doesn't converge. Othewise, we could say $1+1/n\to 1$ so $(1+1/n)^n\to 1.$

Answer (score 5):

You can't write:

$$\lim f(n)g(n)=\lim f(n)\lim g(n)$$ when $f(n)\to 0$ and $g(n)\to \infty.$

You can't recombine terms $$\lim f(n)\lim h(n)=\lim f(n)h(n),$$ where again, $f(n)\to 0$ and $h(n)\to\infty.$

And you can't substitute $f(n)^n$ with $L^n$ just because $f(n)\to L.$

Basically, every step in this argument is wrong.

If we let $f(n)=e^{-2}(1+2/n)^n,$ then we want to compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)^n.$

It is true that $f(n)\to 1,$ but that doesn't mean $f(n)^n\to 1,$ which is the heart of your argument, minus the odd splitting of the limit into two limits.

If we could deduce that from $f(n)\to 1,$ we wouldn't be able to get that $(1+2/n)^n\to e^{2},$ since $1+2/n\to 1,$ also.

The problem is that $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form.

What you need to know is how fast $f(n)$ converges to $1.$

In particular, if $n(f(n)-1)\to L,$ then $f(n)^n\to e^{L}.$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1451245/7933) for a proof of that.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to \infty}{e}^{-2n}\cdot\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\LARGE{e}^{\large{-2n+n^2\ln\left(1+{2\over n}\right)}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\LARGE{e}^{\large{-2n+2n}\Large{\frac{\ln\left(1+{2\over n}\right)}{2\over n}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\LARGE{e}^{\large{4}\Large{\frac{\frac{\ln\left(1+{2\over n}\right)}{2\over n}-1}{\frac2n}}{}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\LARGE{e}^{\large{4}\Large{\frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)-x}{x^2}}{}}\\
\text{(l'Hopital)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\LARGE{e}^{\large{4}\Large{\frac{\frac1{1+x}-1}{2x}}{}}\\
\text{(l'Hopital)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\LARGE{e}^{\large{4}\Large{\frac{-\frac1{(1+x)^2}}{2}}{}}\\
&=\LARGE{e}^{-2}
\end{align}

---

To answer to the OP's question,
$$\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}\approx e^{2n-2}\quad,\quad n>>1$$
rather than $e^{2n}$.
In other words,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(-2n+n^2\ln\left(1+{2\over n}\right)\right)=-2$$
, not $0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. I revised. (And there was a missing of $4$, so I corrected it too.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I revived the $(1+2/n)^{n^2}$ part as it may be clearer, but used $\approx$ instead of $\rightarrow$. Would it be still problematic?

Comment: If $x$ is a tall enough symbol you're tempted to write $\LARGE{e}^x$, it's better to use $\exp(x)$.

Comment: @J.G. Okay. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Write $(1+2/n)^{n^2}=e^{n^2\log(1+2/n)}$. Now, use the fact, from a taylor expansion, that $$\log(1+2/n)=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+O(1/n^3)$$.
Thus, your expression is
$$e^{-2}+O(1/n).$$
Thus the limit is $e^{-2}$.

Comment: That doesn't answer "Where did I go wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot approximate
$$
\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2} \sim e^{2n}
$$
because that doesn't take into account the higher order corrections properly. You can do that using Taylor's series.
Define
$$
f(n) = e^{-2n}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2}
$$
and consider
$$
g(n) = \log\left[
f(n)
\right]
=
n^2\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)-2n\,.
$$
Using the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\mathcal{O}(t^3)$ for small $t$ we have
$$
g(n)
=
2n-2-2n+\mathcal{O}(1/n) \to -2
$$
as $n\to\infty$.
Then
$$
f(n)=e^{g(n)}\to e^{-2}
$$
as $n\to\infty$.
In other words, the correct version of the approximation written at the beginning of the post is
$$
\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2} 
\sim
e^{2n-2}\,.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$L= \lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-2n}\bigg(1+{2\over n}\bigg)^{n^2}$$

The way OP has done it, we have
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-2n}\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^2} \to 0 \lim_{n \to \infty}e^{-2n} \times \lim_{n\to \infty} e^{2n} \to 0 \times \infty \text{(indeterminate)}$$

Let us change it to the form $\infty/\infty$ as

$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\bigg(1+{2\over n}\bigg)^{n^2}
}{e^{2n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\exp\left[n^2\ln\bigg(1+{2\over n}\bigg)\right]}{e^{2n}}$$
Use $\log(1+z)=z-z^2/2+z^3/3..$ to get
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\exp\left[n^2\bigg({2\over n}-{2\over n^2}+{4\over 3 n^3}+...\bigg)\right]}{e^{2n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\exp\left[2n-2+4/(3n)+...\bigg)\right]}{e^{2n}}=e^{-2}$$

Edit: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)g(x)= \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \times \lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ holds only if both limits are finite.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the very fine [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4530058/505767) provided by Thomas Andrews, in order to better understand the issue, let also consider the following basic example

- $a_n =n\to \infty$
- $b_n =\frac1n \to 0$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n b_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} n\cdot \frac1n=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1=1$$

but

$$\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n\right) \cdot \left(\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n\right) = \:"\infty \cdot 0"$$

is undefined.

---

You are also using that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}=e^{2n}$$

which is meaningles (since limit value exists finite or infinite or doesn't exist but can't be a function itself), what is true is that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{2n} =\infty$$

---

Also refer to the related:

- [Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783782/505767)